# Batch QR Code Scanner (Scan multiple qr codes from 1 image)

Tags: windows, scanning, qr-code

I'm using Windows 8, either for gratis / commercial license is ok.

Is there a software that can decode multiple qr codes in one image? Our sales team wants to place several stickers in 1 page, scan it through the scanner, import the image to the program, and export it as csv.

See an example of a scanned image below.

[image]